# .csv not displayed properly in the terminal

Tags: excel, bash, csv

When I enter

```
more trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160823.csv
```

I get the following output:

```
3/14/16 22:00,23.5ature (�C)0.024
3/15/16 16:00,29.5
3/16/16 11:00,39.5
3/17/16 5:00,21.55
3/17/16 23:00,24.5
3/18/16 17:00,28.5
3/19/16 11:00,2855
3/20/16 5:00,23.55
3/20/16 23:00,25.5
3/21/16 17:00,29.5
3/22/16 10:00,26.5
3/23/16 5:00,22.55
3/23/16 23:00,24.5
```

...etc

When I open the file in libreoffice or textedit I get this:

```
,8/23/16
Timezone,-6

Serial No.,3300000039575B41
Location:,LS_trap_6u
High temperature limit (°C),20.1
Low temperature limit (°C),0.03
Date - Time,Temperature (°C)
3/13/16 9:59,26.6
3/13/16 10:59,28.6
3/13/16 11:59,28.6
3/13/16 12:59,27.6
3/13/16 13:59,26.1
3/13/16 14:59,25.6
3/13/16 15:59,26.1
3/13/16 16:59,25.6
3/13/16 17:59,24.6
3/13/16 18:59,24.6
```

When opened in other programs the file has a header, and seemingly data is missing from the output of more. I have numerous other similar files that more displays the same information as other programs.
The command `dos2unix trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160823.csv` doesn't appear to change anything

```
wc -l
```

Indicates there are 0 lines in the file. Which I can't decipher. Why are there differences in the data?

Comment: You have some mad encoding - try running `file trap10c*` to see what format you have.

Comment: This results in: `trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160823.csv: ISO-8859 text, with CR line terminators`

Comment: Try converting it to UTF-8 or ASCII with `iconv`... http://www.f15ijp.com/2010/02/linux-converting-a-file-encoded-in-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8/

Comment: When I do `file` on some of the other files it doesn't output "with CR line terminators" it just says `ISO-8859 text`.Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue like so: 
`mac2unix trap10c_7C000000395C1641_160823.csv`

Once this is done the file outputs fine in terminal. It removes the CR line terminators.